# Search particular matrix in cell array

Tags: matlab, search, matrix, cell-array

So, I have this cell array contains n x 2 matrix in each cell. Here is the sample data :

```
[16 17;17 17]
<6x2 double>
<52x2 double>
[17 17;17 18]
[17 18;17 17]
```

What I am going to do is eliminate the duplicated matrix (matrices with same values or reversed values). in this case is [17 18; 17 17] (5th row), because we already have [17 17; 17 18] (4th row)

I tried using **unique** function but it says that the function just worked for strings. I also tried to find it with **cellfun** like this

```
cellfun(@(x) x==whatToSearch, lineTraced, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

but it says 'Matrix dimension must agree'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if two matrices `A` and `B` are equal, they are still equivalent after some arbitrary permutation of rows?

Comment: No, A and B considered equal if A is a 'mirrored' version of B vice versa (e.g if A=[1 2 3 4 5] and B=[5 4 3 2 1], A and B is considered equal). Thanks for noticing this, I'll update my question.

Comment: If mirrored or flipped, is it upside down flipped or left-right flipped? It appears to be upside-down flipped to me.

Comment: Yes, it is upside-down flipped

Comment: Let me revise my previous example to make it clear. If A=[1 2; 3 4; 5 6] and B=[5 6; 3 4; 1 2], A and B is considered equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. Given a `m x 1` column cell array `C` of matrices, this code deletes the equivalent duplicates. (Here it will delete the 4th and 5th matrices, which are equivalent to the 1st).

```
C{1} = magic(3);
C{2} = magic(4);
C{3} = magic(5);
C{4} = C{1};
C{5} = flipud(C{1});

myEq = @(A,B) isequal(A,B) | isequal(A,flipud(B)); %// equivalence operator tests for same or up-down flipped matrix
C = C(:);                                          %// ensure the cell array is a column
Crep = repmat(C,1,size(C,1));                      %// repeat cell array along rows to get a square
comp = cellfun(myEq,Crep,Crep');                   %'//get a comparison matrix by comparing with transpose
comp = tril(comp) - eye(size(comp));               %// ignore upper triangle and diagonal
idx = find( sum(comp,2)==0 );                      %// get index of matrices we want to keep
result = C(idx);                                   %// get result
```

The output is deletes the 4th and 5th matrices, leaving the first three `magic` matrices:

```
>> result

result = 

[3x3 double]    [4x4 double]    [5x5 double]

>> result{1}, result{2}, result{3}

ans =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2


ans =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1


ans =

    17    24     1     8    15
    23     5     7    14    16
     4     6    13    20    22
    10    12    19    21     3
    11    18    25     2     9
```

Comment: cellfun function throws error, it says:
Error using cellfun
All of the input arguments must be of the same size and shape.

Comment: @AbdullahAlMubarok Hmm... the code works for me. Did you run the exact example I gave? Maybe also try `clear` beforehand to clear the workspace?

Comment: It worked with your example, but when I use it with my sample data above, it throws error. I wonder why you use transpose of C in cellfun, I still have confusion in that part

Comment: I see the problem. Your data is a **column** cell array while mine was a **row**. I changed my code to work with columns. Does it work now? I take the transpose so I can create a "grid" of comparisons that compares every possible pair of matrices in the cell array.

Comment: I see, got it. Yes, the code now works perfectly, thank you eigenchris.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that does what you want.

```
mydup = rand(5,2);
mycell = {mydup;mydup;rand(7,2);rand(3,2);rand(5,2)}

myNewCell = trimCell(mycell)
```

Where `trimCell` is the function below:

```
function myNewCell = trimCell(myCell)


exclude = false(size(myCell));
for iter = 1:size(myCell,1)
    toCompare = myCell{iter};
    comparisons = cellfun(@(x) all(size(x)==size(toCompare)) && myEquals(x, toCompare),myCell);
    % comparisons has at least 1 true in it, because toCompare==toCompare
    exclude(iter) = sum(comparisons)>1;
end

myNewCell = myCell(~exclude);

end

function boolValue = myEquals(x,y)

assert(all(size(x)==size(y)));

boolValue = true;
for iter = 1:size(x,1)
    thisRow = all(sort(x(iter,:))==sort(y(iter,:)));
    boolValue = boolValue && thisRow;
    if ~boolValue
       return 
    end

end

end
```

Basically, what this function does, is, for each matrix in the cell it checks first if the sizes are equal. If the sizes aren't equal, then we know the matrices aren't equal, even if we reorder the rows.

If they are the same size, then we need to check if they're equal after row reordering. That's accomplished by the function `myEquals` which goes through row by row and sorts the rows before comparing them. It exits with `false` on the first row it finds that is not equal after reordering.

Hope this helps,
Andrew

Comment: Nice idea with the sorting. I just have one suggestion: you can check if two matrices `A` and `B` are equal using `isequal(A,B)`, so you can sort once and do the check in one line.